# typescript multiple return type methods not accounted for

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, aws-sdk-js

I am getting following error when I am using aws-sdk in angular2 (typescript)

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
    AWS.config.credentials.get
        [ts]
        Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Credentials | CredentialsOptions'.
          Property 'get' does not exist on type 'CredentialsOptions'.
```

get does not exist on CredentialsOptions but it does exist on Credentials. Typescript keeps throwing me off due to this. Any suggestions? Is it a bug in typescript?

I am using "typescript": "~2.3.3"

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js#pre-requisites

Comment: A bug in TS? No, that's the correct behaviour; the method isn't on both of the possible return values, so you (and the compiler) can't assume it will be there. You could narrow it yourself, e.g. `(AWS.config.credentials as Credentials).get`, but if that's not what you actually get your code fails at runtime instead.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe . This makes sense, though typescript picking one of the return types at random is a bit confusing.

Comment: What makes you say it's doing that randomly?! It's telling you about *the one that doesn't have the method you're trying to call*.

Comment: Does it mean that typescript will pick up only the common methods and properties for both return types?

Comment: It knows about the properties of both, *that's how it can tell you one doesn't have get*. Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html or more general documentation on union types.

Answer (score 0):

To basically put jonrsharpe's comment into answer form, TS is doing the right thing here. If the type of the property is `Credentials | CredentialOptions`, then it could be either type, and so it's not safe to call `get` on it since `CredentialsOptions` doesn't have `get`.

More details in the docs for union types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html